# Google app engine behind the scenes?

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

Can someone please help me in understanding how the Google app engine actually works with Wordpress?

I have successfully deployed a project which uses wordpress - all my media files, and plugins work, I uploaded my DB with the correct paths - what I want to understand is that when I press deploy, where does the project actually deploy? If I want to modify a file in the installation on google, how do I do that? To sum it up, how does it work behind the scenes?

Comment: you project is deployed to a cloud data centre. Exactly where you'll never know. If you want to modify a file in the install then you'll have to re-deploy as you can't edit the files once they are live.

Comment: Thank you! But since media files are uploaded into the file system and the DB both (the path only in the DB), if I add an image into my local system, I will have to re-deploy it each time? But if I add a post, then I will have to re-import my DB also..? Isn't that an overhead?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project contains a starter project with some preset plugins that help.

Comment: WP works otherwise just fine, but you'll need to set it to upload files to a separate file server (e.g. Google Cloud Storage) as the filesystem is read -only in App Engine.

Comment: yes, if you want to change an image that resides on the instance's file system you'll have to re-deploy.

Comment: @ojrask can you please guide on how to do that further? I have been able to deploy the Github Project successfully right at the start, now I have a complete website running.  https://black-backup-96302.appspot.com/ this is my deployment, please do have a look!